# Mapping Not being updated in contract while sending data from another contract

Tags: mapping, ethereum, solidity, modifier

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
contract t1{
    mapping(address => uint256[]) AllSpecialNFT;
    function addNewVal( uint _tokenId) public {
        AllSpecialNFT[msg.sender].push(_tokenId);
    }
    function findSize() public view returns(uint){
        return AllSpecialNFT[msg.sender].length;
    }
    
}
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
import './t1.sol';
contract t2 {
    t1 _t1;
    constructor(t1 t1_){
        _t1 = t1_;
    }
    
    function callandAdd(uint _tokenId) public{
        _t1.addNewVal(_tokenId);
    }
    
    
}
```

This code runs successfully, and is able to add the data in the mapping. But, this does not change the size in the T1 contract. Is there any way i can update add new elements in the mapping and update the size of the contract?

I was expecting that the size of array in mapping to be increased after calling the function callandVal().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i was able to update the mapping from another contract by simply adding a new parameter in the function.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
contract t1{
    mapping(address => uint256[]) AllSpecialNFT;
    function addNewVal(address _off, uint _tokenId) public {
        AllSpecialNFT[_off].push(_tokenId);
    }
    function findSize(address _off) public view returns(uint){
        return AllSpecialNFT[_off].length;
    }
    
}
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
import './t1.sol';
contract t2 {
    t1 _t1;
    constructor(t1 t1_){
        _t1 = t1_;
    }
    
    function callandAdd(uint _tokenId) public{
        _t1.addNewVal(msg.sender,_tokenId);
    }
    
    
}
```